# CKEditor - PasteFromWord adding a class to attributes

Tags: javascript, attributes, ckeditor

I'm trying to force an attribute to be added to specific links when using the PasteFromWord plugin for CKEditor.

I'm looking at the following section from the default.js within the pastefromword/filter folder but nothing seems to make any difference to the pasted code.

```
a: function(a) {
    a = a.attributes;
    a.href && a.href.match(/^file:\/\/\/[\S]+#/i) && (a.href = a.href.replace(/^file:\/\/\/[^#]+/i, ""))
}
```

I've tried a.setAttribute('class','myclass'), a.class='myclass' but nothing is added.

I would like it to check if the a.href contains the word 'javascript' and add the class attribute if it does.

Am I even looking in the right place?

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of CKEditor are you using?

Comment: @Atzmon - using CKEditor 4 - thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution (or hack) applies to CKEditor 4.5.7 so you may need to adjust to fit to your specific version.

First, you are correct about the location to check the `href` and add your class, so you can this code or something similar:

```
a: function(a) {
    a = a.attributes;
    if (attrs.href && attrs.href.indexOf('javascript') != -1) {
        attrs.class = 'myclass';
    }
```

Next, find this code further down within the very long `getRules` function (it may look a little different depending on your version):

```
'class': function (value, element) {
    if ( element.classWhiteList && element.classWhiteList.indexOf( ' ' + value + ' ' ) != -1 )  {
        return value;
    }
    return false;
},
```

Now you need to override the class filter. The easiest hack is to add your class name inline, hard-coded, like this:

```
'class': function (value, element) {
    if ( (value == 'myclass') || ( element.classWhiteList && element.classWhiteList.indexOf( ' ' + value + ' ' ) != -1 ) ) {
        return value;
    }
    return false;
},
```

Now you'll get `myclass` added to your pasted links, if they contain the string 'javascript'.

Comment: Thx Atzmon - will check this in the morning and let you know

Comment: I tried this today and doesn't seem to add anything - I altered 'attrs' to 'a' to comply with previous line and after checking I also amended the getRules part to comply with the 'getRules: function(a, c) {' rather than (value. element) but still no good. I can't actually now be sure the plugin is even getting used because even simple additions or alerts don't trigger. Will try again tmrw.

Comment: If you're not sure if the plugin is activated, add a `debugger;` command before or after `a = a.attributes;`, clear your browser cache and launch the dev tools (F12 in Chrome). Then paste some content from Word with a hyperlink and see if the execution stops at the debugger command.

Comment: I think there was some conflict with my v4.4.7 and the v4.5.7 so I upgraded to v4.5.7 and all seems fine - thanks very much! v4.7.x seems to be a total rewrite so will stick at 4.5.7 until forced to change again